# VB.NET/XAML Memory Leak on Data change of path (Windows Store App)

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps

I am changing a XAML Path object's data from VB.NET code to achieve an effect in the UI. The code I am using is:

```
Do While SomeCondition
   Await Task.Delay(SomeValue)
   Dim Geom As PathGeometry = New PathGeometry
   Dim Figr As PathFigure = New PathFigure
   Dim MyCurve As QuadraticBezierSegment = New QuadraticBezierSegment
   Figr.StartPoint = New Point(SomeValue, SomeValue)
   MyCurve.Point1 = New Point(SomeValue, SomeValue)
   MyCurve.Point2 = New Point(SomeValue, SomeValue)
   Figr.Segments.Add(MyCurve)
   Geom.Figures.Add(Figr)
   MyPath.Data = Geom
Loop
```

Everything results into perfectly what I wanted. But I noticed there is a **huge memory leak** that ultimately freeze my system after 3 minutes. My tests show that the leak is in the last line of the iteration, i.e.

```
   MyPath.Data = Geom
```

I don't have any experience in handling memory leaks. Please guide me.
Thank you.